# Updating amount of text displayed based on input range

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm writing a simple javascript library to update the amount of text (i.e. number of words) displayed in an element based on the HTML5 input range slider.

I have two functions that perform the algorithm, but they are not displaying on the DOM.

HTML

```
<p>Text example:</p>

<section data-range="true">
  <input type="range" value="90">
  <p>This is some sample text that you can reduce. User Account Control (UAC) is a feature that can help you stay in control of your computer by informing you when a programs makes a change that requires administrator permissions. This can be helpful for several reasons, as it allows the user to view program changes and detect system corruption at a faster time.</p>
</section>
```

JS

```
/*  getInnerText
 *  Get inner text of range section
 *  @param nested child <p> element(s) of range section x
 *  @return array of words in the paragraph
*/
function getInnerText(el) {
    var p  = el;
    var innerText = p.innerText;
    return innerText.split(' ');
}

/*  updateInnerText
*   Update inner text based on range section
*/
function updateInnerText(el) {
    var rangeValue = el.srcElement.value;
    var arrayOfWords = getInnerText(el.srcElement.parentNode.children[1]);

    // update words to range value
    arrayOfWords.splice(arrayOfWords.length, arrayOfWords.length - rangeValue);

    // update values on DOM
    el.srcElement.parentNode.children[1].innerText = arrayOfWords.join(" ");
}
```

Here is a [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/yepokihadu/edit?js,output).

Comment: Just curious but why are you using innerText and not .text()?

Comment: Was just testing type=range...How can you display the actual value at the point on the slider?

Comment: I just post the answer, I hope it may be help you

Comment: @KalpeshRajai i made a working JS Bin but dont know how to share lol

Comment: @kiro112 Just copy the URL from the browser's address bar and paste it and you done the sharing JSBin. :)

Comment: @KalpeshRajai its an edit and i try to paste url in new tab. doesnt work lol.. see my answer just change the js

Comment: @kiro112 There is option for `save and update` JSBin. See the `File` menu on the left top corner and click on the 'Save` or 'Save as template` for save the JSBin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/wohodo/edit?html,js,output)

```
// get all DOM elements with data-range attribute
var rangeElements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-range]");

// for each range element on DOM
for (var i = 0; i < rangeElements.length; i++) {

    // get x DOM element with [data-range] attribute
    var el = rangeElements[i];

    // get inputRange element
    var inputRange = el.children[0];

    // attach event listener
    eventListener(inputRange);

    // Text
    if (el.children[1].nodeName == "P") {
        var origText = el.children[1].innerHTML;
        el.children[1].setAttribute("data-text", origText);
        initilzeInputRange(0, origText.length, origText.length, 1);
    }

    // List
    else if (el.children[1].nodeName == "UL") {

    }

    // Image
    else if (el.children[1].nodeName == "IMG") {

    }
}

/*  initilzeInputRange
 *  Setup the default initial values for input range
 *  @param minimum value, maximum value, default value, step
 */
function initilzeInputRange(min, max, value, step) {
    inputRange.min = min;
    inputRange.max = max;
    inputRange.value = value;
    inputRange.step = step;
}

/*  getInnerText
 *   Get inner text of range section
 *  @param nested child <p> element(s) of range section x
 *  @return array of words in the paragraph
 */
function getInnerText(el) {
    var p  = el;
    var innerText = p.innerText;
    return innerText.split(' ');
}

/*  updateInnerText
 *   Update inner text based on range section
 */
 function updateInnerText(el, len) {
    el.srcElement.nextSibling.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = el.srcElement.nextSibling.nextElementSibling.getAttribute("data-text").substring(0, len);

    // var rangeValue = el.srcElement.value;
    // var arrayOfWords = getInnerText(el.srcElement.parentNode.children[1]);

    // update words to range value
    //arrayOfWords.splice(arrayOfWords.length, arrayOfWords.length - rangeValue);

    // update values on DOM
    //el.srcElement.parentNode.children[1].innerText = arrayOfWords.join(" ");
}

/*  eventListener */
function eventListener(el) {
    el.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        updateInnerText(e, el.value);
        console.log('change~');
    });
}
```

Issue Based from your code:
 1. you are not binding Event on change
 2. you did not save the original text

Comment: There is jQuery available and task will be completed with less code so what is need to write too many code. That also hard to understand and debug.

Comment: @KalpeshRajai yes, there is a jquery equivalent. but according to tags **javascript, dom**

Comment: Thank you @kiro112 - I was looking for a vanilla JS solution, not jQuery. Thanks for taking the time to also explain the issue.

Comment: @kiro112 Any advice on how to get this working with multiple p elements? I'm trying to get it working here - http://jsbin.com/qihariyala/edit?js,output

Comment: @Kyle.Belanger meaning single range input with multiple p?

Comment: @Kyle.Belanger just change the `updateInnerText`.. get the targeted p's and update their value

Comment: @kiro112 http://jsbin.com/desusuhepe/edit?js,output This is what I have almost working, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Hi If I understand your question and what you want to so it is may be help you.

I feel you write too many code of `javascript` I totally changed your coding and implementing in my way.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#myValue").val($("#myText").text());

  $("input[type=range]").change(function(){

       updateInnerText();

  });



});          
    /*  updateInnerText
    *   Update inner text based on range section
    */
    function updateInnerText() {
        var arrayOfWords = $("#myValue").val().split(" ");

        var rangeValue=$("input[type=range]").val();

        var count=parseInt(arrayOfWords.length*rangeValue/100);

        // update words to range value
        arrayOfWords.splice(0, count);

        // update values on DOM
       $("#myText").text(arrayOfWords.join(" "));
    }
```

It almost done, what you want live demo available here take look: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pn01uo1y/1/)

If you still have any question feel free to ask.